# 4 boxes floating next to each other

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to get 4 boxes that float next to each other. For some strange reason, they just won't work, nor does any styling work on them.

http://jsfiddle.net/u99A6/

Here is my HTML:

```
<section>
    <article>
        <div class="1-4-container">
            <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="1-4-container">
            <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="1-4-container">
            <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="1-4-container">
            <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
section {
    width: 100%;
}
section article {
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}

.1-4-container,
.2-4-container,
.3-4-container,
.4-4-container {
    float: left;
}
.1-4-container {
    width: 25%;
}
.2-4-container {
    width: 50%;
}
.3-4-container {
    width: 75%;
}
.4-4-container {
    width: 100%;
}
.1-4-container p strong,
.2-4-container p strong,
.3-4-container p strong,
.4-4-container p strong {
    color: #4c4c4c !important;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.1-4-container p,
.2-4-container p,
.3-4-container p,
.4-4-container p {
    color: #939393;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I personally see nothing wrong with this code, but it just doesn't apply the styling on the `div`s for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is invalid. Classes and IDs cannot start with numbers :)

http://jsfiddle.net/u99A6/1/

Having an alpha character as the start of a class name or ID fixes issues.

```
.hi1-4-container {
    width: 24%;
}
```

For future reference, you can use http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator to validate your CSS to check for any issues. You can also use http://validator.w3.org/ to check your HTML for any validation issues. This will help you debug your code (incorrect CSS syntax, or an extra `</div>` etc.)

Comment: Just some advise because of incompatibility i suggest to simply not use numbers in naming at all.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma while I feel sometimes numbers have some advantages in naming structures, typically I avoid it too.

Comment: usually when i have to use multiple names of the same kind i usually go with first_image, second_image or with top_item.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know what numbers in CSS would cause issues like this. I'll try to avoid using them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If the divs are floating next to each other then the total width must add up to be 100%. You are currently adding all the divs up to be 250%.

So basically you need to make each width 25%

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Numbers Before the Selectors (Div, Id)

Just use alphabets